# How to count characters of other languages in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to count Unicode characters like Arabic or Chinese in a edittext.
I manage to count normal characters using this example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9867992/1282492

I want to limit normal characters to 160 and Unicode characters to 80,
is there anyway i can do this?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT** :
you can do this by converting the text into bytes

so 160 english characters = 160 bytes

and 80 Unicode characters = 160 bytes